# How do I set windows service "command line" parameters through the Parameters subkey?

Tags: c#, windows, service, parameters, registry

The windows service c# walkthrough on msdn says that the service can receive command line style args via the "Paremeters subkey" in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\. Now, I'm assuming that means a sub-foldery looking thing as a child of the  folder in the tree, and not just a value of some type named "Parameters" in the  foldery thing (I tried that with single and multiple string values, didn't work). Also other services I can see in the registry have a Parameters sub-foldery thing. This is my first time writing real windows code :P.

However, none of the values I put into the Parameters subkey (foldery thing) are getting passed as args to my service. Is it because I'm starting the service manually from the service manager? Do the parameters only get passed on auto-start? Or am I just doing it wrong? I've just been using string values (REG_SZ).

The service is going to be running on an embedded windows device, and we'd like to configure each unit once when we put it together via automatic remote registry editing.

Comment: And yes I know about the trick where you add the parameters to the ImagePath value under <MyService>, but that seems gross and hacky if there's another actual system for doing it though. I will use it if it's the only option.

Comment: Also, I just found out about adding parameters through the properties dialog in the service manager. VERY strangely, the parameters I add in there don't show up either, though ones that I add to the end of ImagePath in the registry do :S.

Comment: The parameters in the service manager properties dialog are used when calling StartService() and are passed to ServiceMain() rather than to main().  The Parameters subkey is used for other configuration settings, if you use this method I believe your service is expected to read them from the registry itself.  (This is generally considered preferable to using command line parameters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derp. Missed the step in the walkthrough where you edit the installer code to change the ImagePath line automatically. I'll leave this here in case others suffer the same mistake.